# Counting simultaneous page users

Tags: php, view, counting, simultaneous

As part of a treasure hunt style game I'm using some PHP web pages, I'm only prepared to process a form when I know that 10 people (or more) have that page open (they may  not be looking at it of course!) This may take some time so some people may have gone to the page then given up and closed their browser.
It's easy to create a list of started Session IDs accessible from any any session but I wonder how to identify and remove session IDs that are no longer in use?

I tried to think out a solution using timestamps and ajax but found I was going round in circles

Answer (score 0):

Have the client open a "long poll" back.  If that's disconnected you'll know they aren't there any longer.

Comment: Thanks, but for that solution, I think I need control of the server at a level that I don't have.  It's just a shared server on which I can put web pages.  In my plan there is just one php web page that all the players are accessing.  Of course they don't all get the same info in that page - they need to pool their clues to advance to the next (non IT) stage.